# Extract a part of the value from a row and insert into another column

Tags: extract

I would like to extract specific values from the below column to a new column named Extracted_values.

[image]

[image]

I would like to create an sql query that will give me the above result. I am working in SSMS.

I have created an sql but its not working correctly. Its not extracting the negative values so rather than extracting -1=left blank its extracting 1=left blank

```
SELECT
  Desc,
  CASE 
    WHEN Desc LIKE '%[1-9] =%' THEN SUBSTRING(Desc, PATINDEX('%[1-9] =%', Desc), LEN(Desc))
    WHEN Desc LIKE '%-[1-9] =%' THEN SUBSTRING(Desc, PATINDEX('%-[1-9] =%', Desc), LEN(Desc))
  END AS Extracted_values
FROM table a;
```